# Rails: default scoping being cached by query cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, default, scoping

I got a default scoping like this which is dynamic:

```
default_scope :conditions => ["departure_date >= ?", DateTime.current.beginning_of_day]
```

When I use this code the first day is ok. Lets say first day is 28-03-2011

But the next day seems like it's still using `"departure_date >= 28-03-2011"`

Is my default scoping being cached?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that that code is only being executed *once*, when your app is loaded, and thus the actual date isn't changing. You need to change it to load lazily:

```
default_scope lambda { { :conditions => ["departure_date >= ?", DateTime.current.beginning_of_day] } }
```

This way, `Datetime.current.beginning_of_day` will be evaluated each time you make a query.

Comment: err your answer makes sense to me. But i'm having trouble applying to my default scope because i have include as well. Like this : default_scope :conditions => ["departure_date >= ? and deleted = ?", DateTime.current.beginning_of_day, false], :include => [:origin_city, :destination_city].

Comment: I tried this - default_scope lambda {{:conditions => ["departure_date >= ? and deleted = ?", DateTime.current.beginning_of_day, false]}}, :include => [:origin_city, :destination_city] but I get "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)"

Comment: Everything has to be within the `lambda` block, ie: between the internal curly braces.