# Rails - check column with another column of same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails(ActiveRecord) application, I have a table subscription with 3 column created_at,duration,interval
Given an example

```
| created_at  | duration |  interval  |  
| 22-5-2013   |    1     |  month     |
```

I wanna select record which created_at equal to (Date.today - duration.interval) (here Date.today - 1.month)
How can I do this with where clause?
do I need to use join same table?
I don't have any clue.

Comment: Do you want to do it as a validation before saving the record? Why a where clause?

Comment: @cortex I wanna select records which created_at is 1 month ago.(or 3 years ago or 2 weeks ago).interval can be week,month or year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess here, but are you looking for subscriptions that have expired? 
If so I would suggest instead of doing what you're planning, change your application to store the expiry date from the outset. You can easily write a migration to add an expiry date column and fill it in now, then you can add a really simple scope to check if a subscription has expired.

Migrate:

```
add_column :subscriptions, :expiry_date, :datetime

Subscription.reset_column_information

Subscription.all.each do |subscription|
  duration = 0

  switch subscription.interval
    case 'year'
      duration = subscription.duration * 365
    case 'month'
      duration = subscription.duration * 30
    case 'week'
      duration = subscription.duration * 7     
  end

  subscription.update_attribute(:expiry_date, subscription.created_at + duration.days)
end
```

Model:

```
scope :expired, lambda{ where("expiry_date <= ?", Time.now) }
```

Comment: I appreciate this and I am gonna use this method.But to make me happy, Is there any way to do this in my way?

Comment: I'm very glad I could help! @MrYoshiji has given a suggestion below for doing it with SQL.

Comment: My solution works on PostGres, I don't know about MySQL. Also, the lambda is not required here (lambda expects an argument):  `scope :expired, where("expiry_date <= ?", Time.now)` is enough, OR a better way with your lambda: `scope :expired, lambda{ |date| where("expiry_date <= ?", date.try(:to_date) || Date.today) }` and then usable with `Subscription.expired` or `Subscription.expired('2012-12-12')` to get the expired subscriptions at either today or another date

Comment: Hi @MrYoshiji, the lambda is required to make the scope reevaluate. If you leave it off then the code is evaluated once and the Time.now stays at that value in the cache. - A longer explanation of this can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257452/rails-default-scoping-being-cached-by-query-cache

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work for you (worked with PostGre SQL):

```
Subscription.where("CAST(created_at AS DATE) = (CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month')")
```

I can't get it to work with columns, but maybe this can give you the beginning of it:

```
Subscription
  .select("subscriptions.*, subscriptions.duration || ' ' || subscriptions.interval AS my_interval")
  .where("CAST(created_at AS DATE) = (CURRENT_DATE + interval my_interval)")
```

And then there is plenty of posts about having a variable inside the interval function:

- [PostgreSQL how to concat interval value '2 days'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376350/postgresql-how-to-concat-interval-value-2-days)
- [Using a variable period in an interval in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796657/using-a-variable-period-in-an-interval-in-postgres)
- http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050309091736.GA29736@winnie.fuhr.org

## Ah! Got it to work (on PostGre SQL):

```
Subscription.where("CAST(created_at AS DATE) = (CURRENT_DATE - (subscriptions.duration || ' ' || subscriptions.interval)::interval )")
```

Comment: I can't convert this to mysql. better I use Matt's method

Comment: There is probably the equivalent in MySQL, but @Matt 's answer is a good way for the same purpose.